# How can i make a div element fadeout slow when using the transition function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i make a div element fadeout slow when using the transition function

```js
$('.masthead').visibility({
  once: false,
  onBottomPassed: function() {
    $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade in');
    $('.fixed.menu').animate({
      height: 80
    }, 500); //animate the menu to the width of 80
  },
  onBottomPassedReverse: function() {
    $('.fixed.menu').animate({
      height: 50
    }, 500); //animate the menu back to the original width
    $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade out');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="masthead">
<div id="fixed-menu">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` to create a [mcve] - it is not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) fadeIn() and fadeOut()

```
$(".fixed.menu").fadeIn("slow");
```

and

```
$(".fixed.menu").fadeOut("slow");
```